# Erro ao utilizar bibliotecas no PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando adicionar o seguinte:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/settings.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/resources.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/utils.php';

use Spire\Settings;
use Spire\Resources;
use Spire\Utils;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Silex\Application;
```

Porém o servidor me retorna erro onde há o uso da barra invertida ("\"). Qual a configuração necessária para que o servidor reconheça da forma correta?

Comment: Configuração necessária: **(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)**

Comment: Vou verificar agora a versão do PHP

Comment: realmente, a versão do php no servidor é a 5.2.17. Não teria como funcionar. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces são suportados a partir da versão 5.3 do php, provavelmente você está utilizando uma versão anterior.

Answer (score 2):

O erro se dá devido ao uso de Namespaces no seu código.

Repare no uso da palavra `use` em seu código. Nessa parte da sua aplicação ela é utilizada para importar o Namespace específico que será utilizado em seu código.

Conforme mencionado pelo Papa Charlie em comentários, o PHP suporta Namespaces a partir da versão 5.3 somente.

Mais informações sobre Namespace:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.php